# PyCharm: is there a way to stop code folds from auto-expanding when moving the cursor past them?

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to make code or comment folds stay folded in `pycharm` when passing over those comments with the cursor while using the arrow keys?

Comment: They stay folded for me... Only when hovering with the mouse next to the `...` it gives a preview but still stay folded

Comment: Weird, they jump open for me; I am using `vi` mode.  Of course, now they are not. What happens on Windows, stays on Windows, I guess. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  @Tomerikoo

Comment: haha LOL. So it is fine now?

Comment: I think so :) +1

Comment: Happened to me too, around the same time this was posted [PyCharm + IdeaVim : how to disable auto-unfolding on caret touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64337924) with a detailed description and linking to the JetBrains bugtracker.