# PyCharm + IdeaVim : how to disable auto-unfolding on caret touch?

Tags: pycharm, folding, ideavim

When editing folded Python code with IdeaVim, if the caret/cursor touches a folded zone represented by `...` (or `region_name` if using a `#region` tag), the folded section immediately unfolds.
I'd like to disable this behavior so that no fold ever unfolds unless specifically told to do so with a specific command.

Notes:

- I use PyCharm Community 2018.3.7, with IdeaVim 0.57, on Windows 10.
- This problem doesn't occur when I'm not in IdeaVim mode (so it's not PyCharm's "fault").
- This problem doesn't occur in Neovim 0.4.3, I guess it doesn't in other *Vims
- This doesn't affect all folded zones. Chiefly `#region`/`#endregion` folds and long comments, but not folded functions.
- This behavior seems a little random. Sometimes the zone will only unfold if I go right or left when the caret is on the `...` zone, sometimes it unfolds even if I'm just "passing through" with up or down.

**EDIT (based on @Feedforward's comment below)**:

This bug was signaled here on jetBrain's bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-629

It was dismissed because the problem was "non-reproducible". I'll see if there's a way to arrange that, but apparently there's no hope of solving this problem anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to disable it because it's more like a bug in IdeaVim. You can file an issue on the bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM

Comment: Darn, you're right. It' mentioned here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-629, but it was dimissed on the grounds that it was not reproducible and that this is the normal way Vim operates (I disagree).
I might try to take another shot at it if I have more some time to spare on this issue, but it's not getting fixed anytime soon.
I'm still leaving this question open in case the PyCharm fairy sees it and points out an obscure parameter set that takes care of it.
And I don't know if a question should be marked as "Solved" if the solution is "well, you're shafted".